# Python garbage collection with nested class/circular references/reference cycle

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection, circular-reference

I have the following nested structure:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class InnerClass:
    def __init__(self, outer_class):
        self.outer_class = outer_class

    def __del__(self):
        print("Inner class deleted")


class OuterClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inner_class = InnerClass(self)

    def __del__(self):
        print("Outer class deleted")


def scope():
    oc = OuterClass()
    # include this line to see garbage collection working as intended
    # del oc.inner_class


scope()
print("Left scope, but instances were not garbage collected")
input("About to terminate program, you will see garbage collection right after")
```

Is there any way to get a nested structure like this to work with garbage collection? Or should such structures *always* be avoided?

**Edit**: Added better keywords as suggested by LeventeSimofi.

Comment: Searching for "python garbage collection, circular references" is a great place to start. I think you can use weakrefs in the inner class, I am not sure. I will answer your question after a small research.

Comment: Hi @LeventeSimofi ! Thanks for suggesting this. I was missing some of the jargon and didn't get on the right track. I've added the additional buzzwords and was able to answer my own question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the suggestion from Levente Simofi to use weak references, this works as intended:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import weakref


class InnerClass:
    def __init__(self, outer_class):
        self._outer_class_wr = weakref.ref(outer_class)
        print(f"Initialized inner class with outer class {outer_class}")

    @property
    def out_class(self):
        return self._outer_class_wr()


    def __del__(self):
        print("Inner class deleted")


class OuterClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inner_class = InnerClass(self)

    def __del__(self):
        print("Outer class deleted")


def scope():
    ic = OuterClass()

scope()
print("Left scope, you should have seen garbage collection")
input("About to terminate program")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am glad you made it work!

I get the same solution, along with this less practical alternative:

```
import gc  # importing the garbage collector module

class InnerClass:
    def __init__(self, outer_class):
        self.outer_class = outer_class

    def __del__(self):
        print("Inner class deleted")        


class OuterClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inner_class = InnerClass(self)

    def __del__(self):
        print("Outer class deleted")


def scope():
    oc = OuterClass()
    input("Press enter to unscope")

scope()
print('Collecting...')
n = gc.collect()
```

Python has generational **garbage collection** along with the refcounting. It is executed automatically in the background (here I called it manually). This snippet shows that your objects will be deleted (later, when it is needed) too if you do not use weakrefs, they won't create memory leaks.

Search for **generational garbage collection** and read the articles, if you want to know when will it happen, or how it is working. It is basically an algorithm, which gets rid of circular and self references, which can not be solved with **reference counting**.